# The buttons "show, edit, delete" don't appear

Tags: java, android, xml

The buttons "show, edit, delete" don't appear. I used both of Linear and constraint.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBAlL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep85x.png)

I tried many things but still doesn't show. I hope to fix this problem.
Her is my xml code for note.item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Note Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Note Description" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Note Category" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Why didn't you add an Android tag instead of an XML tag? You have an issue with Android, not processing XML.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a small screen and the screen could not show all contents on a single screen. trying adding a ScrollView to parent layout or an emulator with a large screen if still it doesn't solve your problem. do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Adapter class and share with us. Your XML file seems like true. But maybe you make a mistake in your Adapter class. I think you forget to identify the buttons in Adapter class.

and why don't use `ConstraintLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` in CardView ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't use an adapter, but I used UI elements in MainActivity, and below is my code. I've already used ConstraintLayout, but the buttons still don't appear:

```
package com.example.notesapp_ab;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.PopupMenu;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NoteViewModel noteViewModel;
    private LinearLayout notesDescription;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notesDescription = findViewById(R.id.notesDescription);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        // Initialize the ViewModel
        noteViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(NoteViewModel.class);

        fab.setOnClickListener(this::showPopupMenu);

        // Observe the LiveData object and update UI
        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, this::displayNotes);

        SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                noteViewModel.searchNotes(query).observe(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this::displayNotes);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                noteViewModel.searchNotes(newText).observe(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this::displayNotes);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_note) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNoteActivity.class));
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.show_all_notes) {
                noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, this::displayNotes);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }

    private void displayNotes(List<Note> notes) {
        notesDescription.removeAllViews();
        for (Note note : notes) {
            createNoteView(note);
        }
    }




    private void createNoteView(Note note) {
        View noteView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.note_item, notesDescription, false);

        TextView titleTextView = noteView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        TextView descriptionTextView = noteView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
        TextView categoryTextView = noteView.findViewById(R.id.categoryTextView);
        Button showButton = noteView.findViewById(R.id.showButton);
        Button editButton = noteView.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
        Button deleteButton = noteView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);

        titleTextView.setText(note.getTitle());
        descriptionTextView.setText(note.getDescription());
        categoryTextView.setText(note.getCategory());

        showButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // TODO: -------
        });

        editButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditNoteActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NOTE_ID", note.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // TODO: --------
        });

        notesDescription.addView(noteView);
    }








    private SpannableStringBuilder applyColorsToCategories(String categories) {
        SpannableStringBuilder spannableBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        String[] categoryArray = categories.split(", ");
        int start = 0;

        for (String category : categoryArray) {
            int color = getColorForCategory(category);
            int end = start + category.length();
            spannableBuilder.append(category);

            if (color != -1) {
                spannableBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), start, end, SpannableStringBuilder.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }

            start = end + 2; // Account for the comma and space
            if (categoryArray.length > 1 && start < spannableBuilder.length()) {
                spannableBuilder.append(", ");
            }
        }

        return spannableBuilder;
    }

    private int getColorForCategory(String category) {
        switch (category.trim()) {
            case "Todo":
                return ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blue);
            case "Important":
                return ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red);
            case "Idea":
                return ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yellow);
            default:
                return -1; // No color
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some bilds of my projekt.

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqhOe.jpg)

[Button Layout in note.item.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDwVh.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).